# SAMP Pawno mysql r41-4 invalid connection handle '1'

Tags: mysql, pawn

I've encountered a problem with latest MySQL r41-4 release.
I'm getting invalid connection handle '1' error.

code : https://pastebin.com/wTc7BbtD

For example, if the non registered player enters server for the first time:

```
public  PlayerExists(playerid)
{
        if (cache_num_rows() < 1)
        {
            SCM(playerid,COLOR_RED, "NOT REGISTERED");
        }
        else
        {
            SCM(playerid,COLOR_GREEN, "REGISTERED");
        }
}
```

This function works fine

But if any other (or same) non registered player enters the server that public doesn't work, and I'm getting invalid connection handle '1' error.

I've been trying to understand what I'm doing wrong for hours. Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Please add your code to the question instead of using pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    // This is a comment
// uncomment the line below if you want to write a filterscript
//#define FILTERSCRIPT

#include <a_samp>
#include <fix>
#include "streamer"
#include "a_actor"
#include "a_mysql"
#include "dc_cmd"
#include "sscanf2"
#include <mxdate>
#include <foreach>
//=======================================[ Дефайны ]========================================================================

//--------------База данных-------------

#define     SQL_HOST    "localhost"
#define     SQL_USER    "root"
#define     SQL_PASS    "mypw"
#define     SQL_DB     "mydb"

//-------------Дефайны функций----------
#define     SCM             SendClientMessage
#define     SCMTA           SendClientMessageToAll
#define     SPD             ShowPlayerDialog

//-------------Дефайны цвета------------
#define  COLOR_GREY   0xAFAFAFAA
#define     COLOR_YELLOW     0xF7FF00FF
#define     COLOR_WHITE     0xFFFFFFFF
#define     COLOR_RED        0xF0320CFF
#define     COLOR_ORANGEYELLOW  0xFFDF0FFF
#define     COLOR_LIGHTRED      0xFF4530FF
#define     COLOR_LIGHTGREY     0xD1D1D1FF
#define     COLOR_BLUE          0x3657FFFF
#define     COLOR_SALAD         0xA0FF33FF
#define     COLOR_GREEN         0x4BCC2BFF
#define     COLOR_ORANGE        0xFF7A05FF

#define  SERVER_NAME  "Dawn RolePlay"//㡭饠池

//----------------------аᣨ젠池-------------------
new rules[] =
"{FFDA1F}1. ϱ{FFFFFF}\n"\
"-Ƞ౥ 鲯לּ询᳼ 쿡鳻, 糧 鬨 CLEO ೻\n"\
"-Ƞ౥DeathMatch (DM) -  衭ᮥ塢 餰﫠졡槠౨��\n"\
"-Ƞ౥ ᳼ 餰﫮⡭ࡱࡢ(�䥥 ﮨ ௿㬿�� ⡨䱥)\n"\
"-Ƞ౥  ല欠襠 쨠콡 ᣲ"\
"-Ƞ౥ 鳼 ࡳ賠⡶欿��Ქ ﲠᥠ��\n"\
"-Ƞ౥ 鲯לּ询ᮨ塢館吝ﲲ橠池 嬿 ᮨ��屳䩬 餰﫠흮",
rules_1[] =
"{FFDA1F}2. а﷥⺥{FFFFFF}\n"\
"-Ƞ౥�, ﲪﱡ즭饠屳䩵 餰﫮㝮"\
"-Ƞ౥ 軠屳䩬 餰﫠젨ﳭﲿ��餰�౮��"\
"-Ƞ౥ ੱ᳼ ﬠ(ya zawel na server"")\n"\
"-Ƞ౥ 쿡ῠ᭠ ﮭ鵠\n"\
"-Ƞ౥ ��鳼 (��ﱿ婭᫮㼥 ��쨠��硱�쯢褐誜n",
rules_2[] =
"{FFDA1F}3. d�鲲��FFFF}\n"\
"-Υ泌� ᥬ鮨��池 �� ‵ 鿠塭 ౠ㩫\n"\
"-d�鲲���欼㼡鱠沠�� ��嬿 롦寣ﮪ冷 “n"\
"-Ҡ騠���鿠鬨 ��硢 (௱쥥衯ﲲ 硫)\n"\
"-Ʊ쨠�� ��⼫࡯ࡪ 㡬 ﹨⯷ 鳥 ᥬ鮨��";

enum player
{
 ID[6],
 NAME[MAX_PLAYER_NAME +1],
 MONEY[128],
 LEVEL[4],
}
new pInfo[MAX_PLAYERS][player];

new query[256];

main()
{
 print("\n----------------------------------");
 print(" Blank Gamemode by your name here");
 print("----------------------------------\n");
}
//new MySQL: sql;
new MySQL: cHandle;
public OnGameModeInit()
{
 //=======================================[ Ү楨饠诩 塭 ]==================================================
    new MySQLOpt: option_id = mysql_init_options(); // ϯ��MySQL
    mysql_set_option(option_id, AUTO_RECONNECT, true); // b汥௤묾��半    cHandle = mysql_connect(SQL_HOST, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS, SQL_DB, option_id); // ԭ��嫫��鿍
    if(cHandle == MYSQL_INVALID_HANDLE || mysql_errno(cHandle) != 0) // ௤묾��塪 ⡧塤ᮭ {
  print("[MySQL] Υ ﲼ 鳼 鮥 诩 塭."); // û㯤 ��믭

  SendRconCommand("exit"); // ϱ㫠 池
  return 1;
 }
    print("[MySQL] Ү楨饠诩 塭 즭");
 //mysql_log(ERROR | WARNING);
 mysql_log(ERROR | WARNING);

 DisableInteriorEnterExits();
 EnableStuntBonusForAll(0);
 SetGameModeText("test");
 SendRconCommand("hostname "SERVER_NAME"");
 rules[sizeof(rules)-1] = '\n';
 rules_1[sizeof(rules_1)-1] = '\n';
 rules_2[sizeof(rules_2)-1] = '\0';
 AddPlayerClass(0,1755.1631,-1894.1062,13.5568,268.8526,0,0,0,0,0,0);
 return 1;
}
public OnGameModeExit()
{
 mysql_close(); // Ƞ뱻㡥족捻鮥 诩 塭
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerRequestClass(playerid, classid)
{
 SetPlayerPos(playerid, 1958.3783, 1343.1572, 15.3746);
 SetPlayerCameraPos(playerid, 1958.3783, 1343.1572, 15.3746);
 SetPlayerCameraLookAt(playerid, 1958.3783, 1343.1572, 15.3746);
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerConnect(playerid)
{
 GetPlayerName(playerid, pInfo[playerid][NAME], MAX_PLAYER_NAME);
 SetTimerEx("CheckPlayerExistance", 1000, 0, "i", playerid);
 return 1;
}
public OnPlayerDisconnect(playerid, reason)
{
 //save_account(playerid);
 mysql_close();
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerSpawn(playerid)
{
 clear_player(playerid);
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerDeath(playerid, killerid, reason)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnVehicleSpawn(vehicleid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnVehicleDeath(vehicleid, killerid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerText(playerid, text[])
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerCommandText(playerid, cmdtext[])
{
 if (strcmp("/test", cmdtext, true, 10) == 0)
 {
  GivePlayerMoney(playerid, 50000);
  // Do something here
  return 1;
 }
 return 0;
}

public OnPlayerEnterVehicle(playerid, vehicleid, ispassenger)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerExitVehicle(playerid, vehicleid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerStateChange(playerid, newstate, oldstate)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerEnterCheckpoint(playerid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerLeaveCheckpoint(playerid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerEnterRaceCheckpoint(playerid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerLeaveRaceCheckpoint(playerid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnRconCommand(cmd[])
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerRequestSpawn(playerid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnObjectMoved(objectid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerObjectMoved(playerid, objectid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerPickUpPickup(playerid, pickupid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnVehicleMod(playerid, vehicleid, componentid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnVehiclePaintjob(playerid, vehicleid, paintjobid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnVehicleRespray(playerid, vehicleid, color1, color2)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerSelectedMenuRow(playerid, row)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerExitedMenu(playerid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerInteriorChange(playerid, newinteriorid, oldinteriorid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerKeyStateChange(playerid, newkeys, oldkeys)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnRconLoginAttempt(ip[], password[], success)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerUpdate(playerid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerStreamIn(playerid, forplayerid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerStreamOut(playerid, forplayerid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnVehicleStreamIn(vehicleid, forplayerid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnVehicleStreamOut(vehicleid, forplayerid)
{
 return 1;
}

public OnDialogResponse(playerid, dialogid, response, listitem, inputtext[])
{
 switch(dialogid)
 {
  case 1:
  {
   if(!response)
   {
    SPD(playerid, 35, DIALOG_STYLE_MSGBOX, "{FFEF0D}ϸ颪ࢬ "01", "Ƞ뱻 "");
    SCM(playerid, COLOR_RED, "â楨q(/quit) ��골.");
    Kick(playerid);
    return 1;
   }
   else
   {
    if(!strlen(inputtext) || strlen(inputtext) < 8 || strlen(inputtext) > 16)
    {
     SCM(playerid, COLOR_RED, "[Ҩᝠϸ颪ຠͨᬼ 嬨 ࡰ﬿ 8 אַ⬠�콭ῠ16.");
    }
    else
    {
     new Characters[][2] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
     for(new i=0; i<sizeof(Characters); i++)
     {
      if(strfind(pInfo[playerid][NAME], Characters[i], true) != -1)
      {
       {
        SPD(playerid, 35, DIALOG_STYLE_MSGBOX, "{FFEF0D}ϸ颪ࢬ "àꡭ塤ﬦ歠���� ɧ�鳥 椮 衯ﱨ椨��, "Ƞ뱻 "");
        SCM(playerid, COLOR_RED, "â楨q(/quit) ��골.");
        Kick(playerid);
        return 1;
       }
      }
     }
     SetPVarString(playerid, "reg_pass", inputtext);
     SPD(playerid, 2, DIALOG_STYLE_INPUT, "{1472FF}ѥ䲲��ޫ櫲ῠ௷ "{FFFFFF}â楨履�� ௷ɱ௫�� 椮, 㻠泥 㯱ﲲ ᫪ᴭ⡱촷ᥠ㨫ﭠ 鬨 沫衧ᢳ妲塯ᱮ켮\n\nΠ email �㼸즬 볮   14 宥顂禲杮র檲衯橠嬿 ௤祥 ௷n\nԡ楨 ⡯콭ﲲ衢㯤ࡨ �塜"Š즥\"", "Š즥", "");
    }
   }
  }
  case 2:
  {
   if(!response)
   {
    
   }
   else
   {
    SPD(playerid, 3, DIALOG_STYLE_INPUT, "{1472FF}ѥ䩱鿠- ѥ��뢬 "{FFFFFF}Ʊ쨠㻠쨠ṥ족汢汥 ﲠ䮠屳䡜n믲ﱻ顲䱠沬 鳥 椮  ⡯ﬥ 杮\n{C3FF1F}а衤ﲲ駥 㡬蠴-䮠㻠 ௫衢鶴ᤰ᧤殨墬 "Š즥", "аﰳ��
    SetPVarString(playerid, "email", inputtext);
   }
  }
  case 3:
  {
   if(!response)
   {
    SCM(playerid, COLOR_GREY, "Υ��젢);
    SetPVarString(playerid, "referal" , "");
    SPD(playerid, 4, DIALOG_STYLE_MSGBOX, "{1472FF}ѥ䩱鿠- Ю뢬 "û⦰鳥 ௫ 㡸椮 র砢, "ͳ粪謁, "ǥ驢);
   }
   else
   {
    SetPVarString(playerid, "referal" , inputtext);
    SCM(playerid, COLOR_GREY, "Ʊ浥);
    SPD(playerid, 4, DIALOG_STYLE_MSGBOX, "{1472FF}ѥ䩱鿠- Ю뢬 "û⦰鳥 ௫ 㡸椮 র砢, "ͳ粪謁, "ǥ驢);
   }
  }
  case 4:
  {
   if(!response)
   {
    SetPVarInt(playerid, "sex", 2);
    SCM(playerid, COLOR_GREY, "û 㼡 ǥ驠௫.");
    SPD(playerid, 5, DIALOG_STYLE_INPUT, "{1472FF}ѥ䩱鿠- î豠 "Ԫ᧨侮Ჲ 㡸椮 র硜nϲ 18 宠50 ̥"Š즥", "");
   }
   else
   {
    SetPVarInt(playerid, "sex", 1);
    SCM(playerid, COLOR_GREY, "û 㼡 ͳ粪褐௫.");
    SPD(playerid, 5, DIALOG_STYLE_INPUT, "{1472FF}ѥ䩱鿠- î豠 "Ԫ᧨侮Ჲ 㡸椮 র硜nϲ 18 宠50 ̥"Š즥", "");
   }
  }
  case 5:
  {
   if(!response)
   {
    
   }
   else
   {
    new reg_age = strval(inputtext);
    SetPVarInt(playerid, "age", reg_age);
    SPD(playerid, 6, DIALOG_STYLE_INPUT, "{1472FF}ѥ䩱鿠- Π", "Ԫ᧨ᱳ  㮸졯汱ﮠ禜nà箮! ɭ��ᷨ��孨馩.", "Š즥", "");
   }
  }
  case 6:
  {
   if(!response)
   {
    
   }
   else
   {
    SPD(playerid, 7, DIALOG_STYLE_MSGBOX, "{1472FF}ѥ䩱鿠- ϯ䱻","{FFFFFF}û 㰥 餰ᦲ塢 GTA San Andreas Multiplayer (SAMP)?\nͻ ௪᧥졢ᬠ寯שּׂ鳥콭辰롧먠嬿 㡱.", "ή㩷甆, "Ԧ塨䱠뢩;
    SetPVarString(playerid, "about", inputtext);
   }
  }
  case 7:
  {
   if(!response)
   {
    SetPVarInt(playerid, "newbie", 0);
    SCM(playerid, COLOR_GREY, "û 㼡 - Ԧ塨䱠뢩;
    SPD(playerid, 8, DIALOG_STYLE_MSGBOX, "{1472FF}ѥ䩱鿠- аᣨ젠池", rules, "а鮿 "ϲ�ࢩ;
   }
   else
   {
    SetPVarInt(playerid, "newbie", 1);
    SCM(playerid, COLOR_GREY, "û 㼡 - ή㩷甆);
    SPD(playerid, 8, DIALOG_STYLE_MSGBOX, "{1472FF}ѥ䩱鿠- аᣨ젠池", rules, "а鮿 "ϲ�ࢩ;
   }
  }
  case 8:
  {
   if(!response)
   {
    SCM(playerid, COLOR_RED, "[Ҩᝠϸ颪ຠū��࡭ṥ족汢汥 㡬 ⶮ婬狼Შᣨ졬表䱻.");
    Kick(playerid);
   }
   else
   {
    //new query[256];
    new r_pass[32];
    new r_sex;
    new r_email[32];
    new r_referal[32];
    new r_age;
    new r_about[256];
    new r_newbie;
    GetPVarString(playerid, "reg_pass", r_pass, sizeof(r_pass));
    GetPVarString(playerid, "email", r_email, sizeof(r_email));
    GetPVarString(playerid, "referal", r_referal, sizeof(r_referal));
    r_sex = GetPVarInt(playerid, "sex");
    r_age = GetPVarInt(playerid, "age");
    GetPVarString(playerid, "about", r_about, sizeof(r_about));
    r_newbie = GetPVarInt(playerid, "newbie");
    
    format(query, sizeof(query), "INSERT INTO `accounts` (`login`,`password`,`email`,`referal`,`sex`,`age`,`about`,`newbie`) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%d','%d','%s','%d')", pInfo[playerid][NAME],r_pass,r_email,r_referal,r_sex,r_age,r_about,r_newbie);
    mysql_tquery(cHandle, query, "OnPlayerRegistered", "i", playerid);
   }
  }
  case 9:
  {
    if(!response)
    {
     // Ʊ쨠ᬨ 㼵懶
    }
    else
    {
     SetPVarString(playerid, "l_pass", inputtext);
     //new query[128];
     format(query, sizeof(query), "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `login` = '%s' AND `password` = '%s' LIMIT 1",playername(playerid), inputtext);
     mysql_tquery(cHandle, query, "OnPlayerLogin", "r", playername(playerid));
    }
  }
 }
 return 1;
}

public OnPlayerClickPlayer(playerid, clickedplayerid, source)
{
 return 1;
}
public OnPlayerClickMap(playerid, Float:fX, Float:fY, Float:fZ)
{
  SetPlayerPos(playerid, fX, fY, fZ);
  SetPlayerVirtualWorld(playerid, 0);
  SetPlayerInterior(playerid, 0);
 //return 0;
}
//====================================================================
stock playername(playerid)
{
 new pName[MAX_PLAYER_NAME +1];
 GetPlayerName(playerid, pName, sizeof(pName));
 return pName;
}
stock sendername(playerid)
{
 new newname[MAX_PLAYER_NAME];
 GetPlayerName(playerid, newname, sizeof(newname));
 return newname;
}
stock save_account(playerid)
{
 new string[256];
 format(string, sizeof(string), "[SAVE ACCOUNT ON EXIT] User %s Money Ammount : %d", pInfo[playerid][NAME],pInfo[playerid][MONEY]);
 printf(string);
 //new query[256];
 format(query, sizeof(query), "UPDATE `accounts` SET `money` = '%d' WHERE `id` = '%d' LIMIT 1", pInfo[playerid][MONEY], pInfo[playerid][ID]);
 mysql_query(cHandle, query);
 
}
stock give_money(playerid, amount)
{
 pInfo[playerid][MONEY] += amount;
 GivePlayerMoney(playerid, amount);
}
stock clear_player(playerid)
{
    pInfo[playerid][MONEY] = 0;
 pInfo[playerid][ID] = 0;
}
stock LoadPlayerData(playerid)
{
 new query[256];
 format(query, sizeof(query), "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `login` = '%s'", playername(playerid));
 mysql_tquery(sql, query, "OnTest", "r", playerid);
 cache_get_value_name_int(0, "money", pInfo[playerid][MONEY]);
 
 
}
//====================================================================

forward CheckPlayerExistance(playerid);
public  CheckPlayerExistance(playerid)
{
  SetPlayerCameraPos(playerid, 1027.7542, -1075.3053, 109.6629);
        SetPlayerCameraLookAt(playerid, 1028.7198, -1075.5803, 109.6678);
        // ⡬怜 㡰顭᭥ 㩤 ﲪ⡋ﱠҠ        
        //format(query, sizeof query, "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `login` = '%s'", pInfo[playerid][NAME]); // ��᳨ 衯鷻 accounts 衯况믬 ᥥ ⡯ﬥ name
        //mysql_tquery(sql, query, "PlayerExists", "ii", playerid, THREAD_TESTING);

  mysql_format(cHandle, query, sizeof(query), "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `login` = '%e' LIMIT 1",pInfo[playerid][NAME]);
  // the variable 'query' contains now the formatted query (including the escaped string)
  mysql_tquery(cHandle, query, "PlayerExists");
  return 1;
}
forward PlayerExists(playerid);
public  PlayerExists(playerid)
{
        if (cache_num_rows() < 1) // 沫衭᪤殮 0 ᥥ, 䱮ꡤﬦ歠衰椨
        {
   SCM(playerid,COLOR_RED, "NOT REGISTERED");
  }
        else //  ࡥ妭 ᣲﱨ衶鿍
        {
   SCM(playerid,COLOR_GREEN, "REGISTERED");
  }
  return 1;
}
```